How can shared_ptr using -> and . operator with same variable name?
i stuck with a confusion in example below i have declared a shared ptr 'u'
i am using u->data as well as u.use_count()
Since 'u' holds a pointer then how can we use dot operator to call use_count , how it works internally?
how can we use both -> and . with same variable name?
int main() {
std::shared_ptr<test> u = std::make_shared<test>();
u->data = 60;
{
    std::shared_ptr<test> u1 = u;
    u1->data = 99;
}

std::cout << "Value: " << u.use_count() << std::endl;           
return 0;
}

Thanks!

u->something is a dereference of the object held by the smart pointer. u.something is a member function (or member variable, if they were public) of the smart pointer itself.

std::shared_ptr overloads operator-> and operator*.

operator. accesses member functions of the shared_ptr itself, operator-> uses the internally stored pointer (as if it where a normal pointer) and so you then don't use the shared pointer itself but the object it points to

The documentation is quite explanatory

This question is similar to: What can I use instead of the arrow operator, `->`?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

. references the smart pointer.  -> references the object pointed to.

"how can we use both -> and . with same variable name?" -- Why not? An explanation of your perspective would be a good addition to the question. (The fact that you can use both implies that people familiar with the syntax would not share your perspective.)

u->data is (*u).data, *u is test, and is applied to test::data.
u.use_count() is applied to u, calls std::shared_ptr::use_count().
